# Itunes connect: Invalid binary shortly after submitting app

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store-connect

Shortly after submitting my app to itunes connect I get invalid binary as the status. I'm using organizer in xcode to upload it. Validation is ok. I've read several other questions here but none helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my stupid mistake, somehow I didn't use the right certificate to sign the binary. Solved.